# Magento 2.2.7 - How to access custom attributes of the associated products of a grouped product on final_price.phtml

Tags: magento2, grouped-products, object-manager, factory, final-price.phtml

Sorry in advance if this is a silly question. I'm fairly new to backend development.

I have a custom attribute that determines whether or not a price should be visible on the frontend. It works just fine with simple products, but I can't get it to work with grouped products, since it doesn't seem that Magento loads the associated simple products as objects in the template file. As a result, I can't access the values of custom attributes.

Here's that part of the template file:

```
$product = $block->getSaleableItem();

if (!$product->getData(\Vendor\Pricing\Helper\Data::ATTRIBUTE_PRICING_VISIBLE)) {
    return '';
}
```

When this runs for grouped products, getData always returns 0/No even if ATTRIBUTE_PRICING_VISIBLE = Yes. When I try something like getCustomAttribute instead of getData, it returns a null value. Additionally, I tried getResource and got the error "Trying to get property of non-object."

To get the full product to load, I tried the Product Factory method, like so:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Fixes\MagentoCatalog\Plugin\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

  protected $_productloader;  

  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader

    ) {

        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getLoadProduct($id) {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

.phtml file:

```
$productId = $block->getSaleableItem()->getId();
$product = $block->getLoadProduct($productId);

if (!$product->getData(\Vendor\Pricing\Helper\Data::ATTRIBUTE_PRICING_VISIBLE)) {
    return '';
}
```

But this also returns a null error when trying to access that attribute. The only thing that seems to work is Object Manager, which I know is a huge no-no. This is the code that works:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productId = $block->getSaleableItem()->getId();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

<?php if (!$product->getData(\Vendor\Pricing\Helper\Data::ATTRIBUTE_PRICING_VISIBLE)) {
    return '';
} ?>
```

So how can I accomplish this without the use of Object Manager? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome, the way you need to thing of group products is like a shell for all the sub products, within these products there are specific functions to access the child data from what iv read so far you are specifically aiming at the grouped product when in face you should be aiming at the simple products and to do that you would need to get the group product children and you can do this by $product->getChildrenIds($parentId, $required = true) which should return the ids for all sub products allowing you to load them individually and checking the data that way

Comment: Thank you! I'll try your suggestion today and see if I'm successful.